# Merge two CountVectorizers and compute Cosine Similarity

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to implement a technique described in an information retrieval paper, where documents are decomposed into vectors and then, their cosine similarity is computed, much like how it is explained here: http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/

In the example, we have:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

documents = (
    "The sky is blue",
    "The sun is bright",
    "The sun in the sky is bright",
    "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun"
)

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix)
```

However, from time to time I'll get a new document. Is there a way to calculate the cosine similarity of this new document without recreating the `documents` tuple and the `tfidf_matrix`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
new_docs = [
    "This is new doc 1",
    "This is new doc 2",
]
new_tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.predict(new_docs)
cosine_similarity(new_tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

If you think the new docs will have new vocabulary not present in the training dataset, then you should consider retraining the Vectorizer with `tfidf_vectorizer.fit(all_docs)`.